# Add root element to generated json object

Tags: java, json, rest, jpa, jackson

I have java model class look like below.

```
@Entity(name = "bank_um_privilege")
@JsonRootName(value="Privilege")
public class Privilege extends Model {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8307505934865392503L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "privilege_name", nullable = false)
    private String privilegeName;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;
}
```

I created rest full web services for pass values.

```
 @GET
  @Path(WSPath.GET_ALL_USER_PRIVILEGES)
  public Response getUserPrivileges() throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    List<Privilege> userPrivileges = userService.getUserPrivileges();
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    om.configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    return Response.ok(om.writeValueAsString(userPrivileges)).build();
  }
```

I send above privilege list as response. response look like below.

```
     "ArrayList":
   [
       {
           "version": 0,
           "privilegeName": "ADMIN_LOGIN",
           "description": "Login authority to administration application",
           "code": "900",
           "status": 0,
           "category": "User Management"
       },...
```

Now i need add root element to above json object look like that.Need to add "Privilege" name as root name insted of "ArrayList"

```
"privilege":{
           "version": 0,
           "privilegeName": "ADMIN_LOGIN",
           "description": "Login authority to administration application",
           "code": "900",
           "status": 0,
           "category": "User Management"
        },...
```

I am using JPA to persist data.Tell me any one how can i do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Spring` you have default `ObjectMapper` bean which serialize yours objects to `JSON`. You have to override this default bean using below code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
```

Using it, your output should look like you expected.

**UPDATE 1**
In this case when you want to wrap item in collection you have to implement your custom serializer and annotate specific `List<POJO> property` using this serializer. See answer of @Sotirios_Delimanolis for this question: [Jackson JSON List with Object Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22917324/jackson-json-list-with-object-type).

Comment: Well Michal,It is work only parsing an object. but i need to parse list of object.when parsing list to object mapper out put not get entered name as root name.It gets "Array list" as root name.how can i resolve this problem.

Comment: This is my ws 
 @GET
  @Path(WSPath.GET_ALL_USER_PRIVILEGES)
  public Response getUserPrivileges() throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
  
    List<Privilege> userPrivileges = userService.getUserPrivileges();
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    om.configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    return Response.ok(om.writeValueAsString(userPrivileges)).build();
  }