# Jackson JSON List with Object Type

Tags: java, json, serialization, types, jackson

I have to serialize JSON from a list of Objects. The resulting JSON has to look like this:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "models": [
        {
            "model": {
                "id": 23,
                "color": "red"
            }
        },
        {
            "model": {
                "id": 24,
                "color": "green"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am missing the type/key "model" when I simply serialize this:

```
List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>(); // add some new Model(...)
Response r = new Response("success", list); // Response has field "models"
```

Instead I just get this:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "models": [
        {
            "id": 23,
            "color": "red"
        },
        {
            "id": 24,
            "color": "green"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I add "model" for each object without having to write a silly wrapper class with a property "model"?

My classes look like this:

```
public class Response {
    private String status;
    private List<Model> models;
    // getters / setters
}

public class Model {
    private Integer id;
    private String color;
    // getters / setters
}
```

Comment: Your JSON is not valid; object member names must be quoted (hint: "" is a valid JSON Object member name)

Comment: Can you show your `Model` class and `Response` class?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this. You'll have to write your own `JsonSerializer`. Something like

```
class ModelSerializer extends JsonSerializer<List<Model>> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(List<Model> value, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        jgen.writeStartArray();
        for (Model model : value) {
            jgen.writeStartObject();
            jgen.writeObjectField("model", model);
            jgen.writeEndObject();    
        }
        jgen.writeEndArray();
    }

}
```

and then annotate the `models` field so that it uses it

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ModelSerializer.class)
private List<Model> models;
```

This would serialize as

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "models": [
        {
            "model": {
                "id": 1,
                "color": "red"
            }
        },
        {
            "model": {
                "id": 2,
                "color": "green"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If you're both serializing and deserializing this, you'll need a custom deserializer as well.

Answer (score 4):

This is an oldish question, But there is an arguably more idiomatic way of implementing this (I'm using `jackson-databind:2.8.8`):

Define a `ModelSerializer` (That extends `StdSerializer` as recommended by Jackson) that prints your model how you like and use the `@JsonSerialize(contentUsing = ...)` over your collection type:

```
class ModelSerializer extends StdSerializer<Model> {

    public ModelSerializer(){this(null);}
    public ModelSerializer(Class<Model> t){super(t);} // sets `handledType` to the provided class

    @Override
    public void serialize(List<Model> value, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeObjectField("model", value);
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

*Meanwhile, in another file:*

```
class SomethingWithModels {
    // ...
    @JsonSerialize(contentUsing = ModelSerializer.class)
    private Collection<Model> models;
    // ...
}
```

Now you aren't bound to just `List`s of models but may apply this to `Collection`s, `Set`s, Native `[]`s and even the values of `Map`s.

Comment: this code won't compile. First, you have a parameter named value, but are writing 'model'. Also, at least in my jackson, the signature of serialize appears to get a single model, not a list.

Answer (score 0):

**Another approach** is using `StdConverter` class. Here is a working (abbreviated) example:

```java
// MyParentObject.java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

public class MyParentObject {
  @JsonSerialize(converter = ChildListToString.class)
  @JsonDeserialize(converter = StringToChildList.class)
  @JsonProperty
  public List<AChildObject> myChildren;
}
```

```java
// ChildListToString.java

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.StdConverter;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ChildListToString extends StdConverter<List<AChildObject>, String> {
  @Override
  public String convert(List<IntakeModuleUrn> value) {
    // this is just as effective as using Jackson "write array"
    // Try-Catch omitted for brevity
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("[");
    value.stream().map(value -> new ObjectMapper().writeValue(value)).forEach(urnStr -> {
      if(builder.length() > 1) {
        builder.append(", ");
      }

      builder.append("\"").append(urnStr).append("\"");
    });

    builder.append("]");

    return builder.toString();
  }
}
```

```java
// StringToChildList.java

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.StdConverter;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StringToChildList extends StdConverter<String, List<AChildObject>> {

  @Override
  public List<AChildObject> convert(String value) {
    // try - catch omitted here for brevity
      List<String> strings = new ObjectMapper().readValue(value, new TypeReference<List<String>>() {});
      return strings.stream()
          .map(string -> {
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(string, AChildObject.class)
          }).collect(Collectors.toList());

  }
}
```

I like this because it gives you control of serialization and deserialization separately.