# Generic Jackson property with concrete Serializer

Tags: java, json, serialization, types, jackson

I have a generic Response Object that takes a status message and a payload object.

```
public class Response {
    private String status;
    private Object payload;
    // getters / setters
}
```

The object can be any type, including lists or arrays. (Much like here: [Jackson JSON List with Object Type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22917324/132396)).

In the case where the object is a List, I need a serializer and an annotation to tell Jackson about it:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ModelSerializer.class)
private List<Model> models;
```

How can this be achieved in a generic way? I can introduce a common superclass to the object candidates but don't want to "implement" a seperate Response class for each type.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your object mapper by registering the serializer for List as described here : http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule testModule = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));
testModule.addSerializer(new ModelSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(testModule);
```

When serializing your Response, Jackson will use default serialization for all object except for the ones declaring a custom serializer.