# How do I serialize a list of objects with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, annotations

I have a `class A` that I created a custom serializer for. `Class B` has a member variable `private List<A> as;` and some other members with Double as the data type. What do I have to do to serialize/desirialize an object of class B? I know there is an annotation `@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)` but I think it doesn't work with lists. Do I need an additional custom serializer or is there a workaround?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22918204/442030) help?

Comment: Ok, I guess I will create another custom serializer then.